# make64 high32 low32 functions on Mac OS/Linux

Tags: c, linux, macos, 64-bit

Anyone know what library/header is required to use the make64 high32 and low32 functions on 
MacOS or linux. Couldn't find anything on the web.

```
 uint64_t make64(uint32_t high, uint32_t low);
 uint32_t high32(uint64_t value);
 uint32_t low32(uint64_t value);
```

Thanks

Comment: I've never heard of these functions. Where did you encounter them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any library with these functions, just write them:

```
uint64_t make64(uint32_t high, uint32_t low)
{
    return (uint64_t) high << 32 | low;
}

uint32_t high32(uint64_t value)
{
   return value >> 32;
}

uint32_t low32(uint64_t value)
{
    return value;
}
```